# Resolving Couchbase IP through hosted zone or load balancer

Tags: couchbase

We have a Couchbase cluster in AWS, and access it using a Java service. In Java service we put ip addresses so that service can make connection while bootstrapping.

At times, we need to add new nodes or remove existing nodes from the existing cluster. We want to have a flexibility where we should be able to add new nodes and remove all existing nodes.

To make sure that service is still able to make connection to Couchbase we want to use either DNS resolver or load balancer.

I am not sure if it's going to even work ? Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase Java clients make the connection to the instance directly. This helps in improving performance, as the client is talking directly to the node. Any abstraction which we create either through domain name or load balancer will get used only during the bootstrap process (i,e. when the client is trying to make the connection for the first time).

I ended up using AWS hosted zone finally. We can use load balancer as well, but it will be confusing. The load balancers are used to delegate traffic to different instances but in this case, the client directly connects to instances.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late for this response. We have used Network Loadbalancer to bootstrap via Java SDK and it worked. We have not done any performance analysis though.